# How to modify limit number of tags on input with jquery

Tags: jquery, input, plugins, autocomplete, tags

how to modify the tag plugin https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Tag-Input-With-Autocomplete-jQuery-Tagator/

so it only allows selection of **x** numbers of tags and how to allow only tags that are in the "availableTags-option"?

```
    $(function () {
            var $input_tagator1 = $('#input_tagator1');
            var $activate_tagator1 = $('#activate_tagator1');
            $activate_tagator1.click(function () {
                if ($input_tagator1.data('tagator') === undefined) {
                    $input_tagator1.tagator({
                        autocomplete: ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth', 'sixth', 'seventh', 'eighth', 'ninth', 'tenth'],
                        useDimmer: true
                    });
                    $activate_tagator1.val('destroy tagator');
                } else {
                    $input_tagator1.tagator('destroy');
                    $activate_tagator1.val('activate tagator');
                }
            });
            $activate_tagator1.trigger('click');
        });
```

[image]

Comment: Post code attempt please

Comment: Share the code here. the link you have provided doesn't have any code and it does not limit the number of inputs.

Comment: I added my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(function () {
  var $input_tagator1 = $('#input_tagator1');
  var $activate_tagator1 = $('#activate_tagator1');
  $activate_tagator1.click(function () {
    if ($input_tagator1.data('tagator') === undefined) {
      $input_tagator1.tagator({
        autocomplete: ['first', 'second', 'third', 'fourth', 'fifth', 'sixth', 'seventh', 'eighth', 'ninth', 'tenth'],
        useDimmer: true
      });
      $activate_tagator1.val('destroy tagator');
    }
  });
  $activate_tagator1.trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.